# 3 rd party API risk

Tags: web-services, api, advertisement-server

i am trying to understand what are the risk when implementing  and integrate 3 party API like
ComScore, QuantCast, BlueKai, PubMatic, Rubicon?

Can anyone give some advice please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@Milas I would say the biggest problem I have experienced with using 3rd party API things is privacy. When you use other 3rd party API's a user(or you) may have to agree to terms and conditions that you would not normally agree with. There are plenty others, but this is what I have found so far. Best of luck. Read up on terms and conditions to be safe.